# How to disable JSP error checking in WildFly 10

Tags: java, jsp, wildfly-10

In my jsp code and there is an input field which I have used the same attribute twice but with different values.( I have used "disabled" attribute twice within `<sj:submit/>` in below code ). admin and operator are 2 boolean values which are passing from the backend.

```
<s:set id="admin" var="admin"><s:property value="admin" default="true"/></s:set>
<s:set id="operator" var="operator"><s:property value="operator" default="true"/></s:set>    

<sj:submit button="true" value="Submit" name="submit" id="subview" onClick="todo()" 
    disabled="#admin"  disabled="#operator" />
```

This code worked fine for weblogic server, but this code throws an org.apache.jasper.JasperException exception "jsp.error.attribute.duplicate" when using this code with wildfly 10. This exception occurred because of the 2 "disabled" attributes.Since I have to use both "disabled" attributes and I have used this in many pages, I can not change them one by one. Instead, is there a way to disable jsp error checking when using with wildfly 10 ?

Comment: There is a double quote "flying" on your `<sj:submit >>>>>"<<<<< button="true"` is it a typo?

Comment: It was a mistake @Jorge and I removed it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem after some researchs. The answer is "*there is **no** way to disable jsp error checking in wildfly 10,in order to avoid getting  'jsp.error.attribute.duplicate' error*". If you check the attribute parsing method of undertow-io  **['parseAttributes(boolean pageDirective)'](https://github.com/undertow-io/jastow/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/jasper/compiler/Parser.java)** ,you can see that, within the attribute parsing method it checks whether this attribute is a unique one or not, by using a **'UniqueAttributesImpl'** object named as **'attrs'** during the compilation.

```
 Attributes parseAttributes(boolean pageDirective) throws JasperException {
        UniqueAttributesImpl attrs = new UniqueAttributesImpl(pageDirective);

        reader.skipSpaces();
        int ws = 1;

        try {
            while (parseAttribute(attrs)) {
                if (ws == 0 && STRICT_WHITESPACE) {
                    err.jspError(reader.mark(),
                            "jsp.error.attribute.nowhitespace");
                }
                ws = reader.skipSpaces();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Duplicate attribute
            err.jspError(reader.mark(), "jsp.error.attribute.duplicate");
        }

        return attrs;
    }
```

If it found out that this attribute has used more than once, it throws an IllegalArgumentException exception, with the message 'jsp.error.attribute.duplicate'.

This [article](http://www.theglobalvariable.com/why-wildfly-server-throws-jsp-error-attribute-duplicate-and-jsp-error-attribute-nowhitesapce-errors/) explains more about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to disable such checking by setting

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_WHITESPACE=false
```

in WildFly launch file.